# Time multiplication in HH:MM:SS format

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have three fields like "Duration,Repeat,Complete Duration". User will enter the duration in time format(HH:MM:SS) and they will enter the repeat field value like "5,10,4,9,7 etc". Based on the two fields value the complete duration field should be filled.

I have tried using angular NgModel of both text fields and I multiplied the value with repeat field value. But the conversion was not happened properly.

```
<div>  
    <input type="value" [(ngModel)]="user.hrDuration"> 
    <input type="value" [(ngModel)]="user.minDuration">
    <input type="value" [(ngModel)]="user.secDuration">
</div>
<div>
 <input type="value"   [(ngModel)]="user.repeat">
</div>
<div>  
    <input type="value" [(ngModel)]="user.hrDuration*user.repeat"> 
    <input type="value" [(ngModel)]="user.minDuration*user.repeat">
    <input type="value" [(ngModel)]="user.secDuration*user.repeat">
</div>
```

I have tried like this, but the thing is it is directly multiplied the values, I need to convert and then it should multiply with the repeat field value.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can you create a stackblitz example for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the input's input event so you'll know when they're changing:

```
<div>  
    <input type="value" [(ngModel)]="user.hrDuration" (input)="updateResult()"> 
    <input type="value" [(ngModel)]="user.minDuration" (input)="updateResult()">
    <input type="value" [(ngModel)]="user.secDuration" (input)="updateResult()">
</div>
<div>
 <input type="value" [(ngModel)]="user.repeat" (input)="updateResult()">
</div>
<div>  
    <input type="text" [ngModel]="result.hrDuration"> 
    <input type="text" [ngModel]="result.minDuration">
    <input type="text" [ngModel]="result.secDuration">
</div>
```

and then in the Component have the listening method:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  user = {
    hrDuration: 1,
    minDuration: 1,
    secDuration: 1,
    repeat: 1
  }

  result = {
    hrDuration: this.user.hrDuration * this.user.repeat,
    minDuration: this.user.minDuration * this.user.repeat,
    secDuration: this.user.secDuration * this.user.repeat
  }

  updateResult() {
    // do your conversion here
    this.result.hrDuration = this.user.hrDuration * this.user.repeat;
    this.result.minDuration = this.user.minDuration * this.user.repeat;
    this.result.secDuration = this.user.secDuration * this.user.repeat;
  }
}
```

Here is a working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2aukww

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an onchange event listener and a function that returns the result:

HTML:

```
<div>  
    <input type="value" [ngModel]="user.hours" (ngModelChange)="getResult()"> 
    <input type="value" [ngModel]="user.minutes" (ngModelChange)="getResult()">
    <input type="value" [ngModel]="user.seconds" (ngModelChange)="getResult()">
</div>
<div>
 <input type="value" [ngModel]="user.repeat" (ngModelChange)="getResult()">
</div>
<div>  
    <input type="value" (ngModel)="user.result" readonly>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function getResult() {
    if (isNaN($scope.user.hours) ||
        isNaN($scope.user.minutes) ||
        isNaN($scope.user.seconds) ||
        isNaN($scope.user.repeat)) return $scope.user.result = "";

    var total = ($scope.user.hours*60*60 + $scope.user.minutes*60 + $scope.user.seconds) * $scope.user.repeat;

    var hh = Math.floor(total / (60*60));
    if ( hh < 10 ) hh = '0' + hh;

    var diff = total % (60*60);

    var mm =  Math.floor(diff / 60);
    if ( mm < 10 ) mm = '0' + mm;

    var ss = Math.floor(diff % 60);
    if ( ss < 10 ) ss = '0' + ss;

    $scope.user.result = hh + ':' + mm+ ':' + ss;
    // of course you could also output something like
    // 'X hours, Y minutes, Z seconds'
}
```

Showing the result as a single value will show more clearly the final value, since multiplying each variable (hours, minutes and seconds) by the repeats would be less intuitive.